# Is the CI_JOB_TOKEN really not authorized to access the registry API?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

The Gitlab Documentation clearly says that [CI_JOB_TOKEN is valid authorization](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#gitlab-cicd-job-token) for the container registry API. But why, then, does the following when run in an otherwise empty test pipeline yield a 403 forbidden?

```
curl --header  "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/registry/repositories/
```

Even if the JOB_TOKEN inherits permission from the author of the pipeline it should work, since the author (me) can access above API with my personal API token.

What am I missing? And what could I do to debug it?

Answer (score 3):

As of now, the Job Token really does not support these API calls. I just tripped over this as well.

Some people even use [elaborate kludges](https://itnext.io/pimp-your-gitlab-pipeline-permissions-ffdd27be5e1d) to mitigate this.

Comment: Same problem here. I hoped to use `CI_JOB_TOKEN`, but I will need to use a project access token instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2023

As of Gitlab 15.3 (August 2022), this feature is now available.

Documentation:

- [CI_JOB_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html)
- [Packages API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html)
- [Package using CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/index.html#publish-a-generic-package-by-using-cicd)

Comment: The thing that was missing for me was that the package registry did not have CI job tokens "enabled" (I think by default). This actually yielded a 404 when the runner tried to connect, which seems quite misleading to me.